# Display thank you page for Pay Later (ed: was offline) contributions (civicontribute)

Tags: civicontribute, contributions

How do you enable a thank you page for any Pay Later membership? We'd like to redirect them to a page that tells them how to get us their contribution. Are thank you pages only displayed when using a payment processor? How do we display something as reinforcement that we got their submission?

Answer (score 1):

"Offline" in civi can be a misleading term - it means a staff member has entered it in the backend, e.g. using the Memberships - New Membership menu choice. So you can't redirect to a thank-you page there since it's a staff member doing the entry.

If you mean pay-later, then when you configure the contribution page there's a checkbox for "Use a confirmation page?" at the bottom of the Title tab, e.g. at `civicrm/admin/contribute/settings?reset=1&action=update&id=1` (replace id=1 with the id of the appropriate contribution page). Pay later is an option on the Amounts tab.

Comment: Yes, I mean pay-later. We are using a contribution page. But the confirmation page is a  page that displays the information they submitted prior to hitting the final submit. With a PayPal submission, when you get redirected to PayPal, and you hit return to merchant, there's a thank you page that gets displayed. If you're paying pay-later and you hit submit, you stay on that page. There's no thank you page, and no opportunity to display "please send your contribution to xxx". So there's no real confirmation for the person that anything really happens.

Comment: They can get an email receipt but that is after the fact. We would prefer to send them another email and not the receipt because we're gathering info via a profile so want to confirm what they've submitted there.

Comment: If pay later is enabled the 'pay later instructions' are also displayed on the final thank you page (just checked on two of our sites and they appear between the user defined 'thank you' message text and above the contribution section so maybe just a configuration change that's necessary?

Comment: I have the same problem using the Pay later option. CiviCRM used to display a thank-you page (including 'Pay later instructions') when a donation was confirmed. CiviCRM now loads a fresh donation page (at least for pay-later).  Doesn't matter whether a confirmation page is used or not. CiviCRM does record the donation and sends a thank-you email that includes the pay-later instructions.

When I tested our primary donation page (which used to display a thank you page for pay later) it also now loads a fresh donation page. Not sure when it changed (we're up to version 5.50.2)

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem causing the thank-you page to misbehave on pay-later on my sites - while updating a few months ago I missed adding a couple definitions to the settings file (CRM_CRED_KEYS and CIVICRM_SIGN_KEYS). After adding the php code to set these keys the thank-you page displays properly.